# Center two views vertically using NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, uikit, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Imagine this following scenario. You have a UIImageView and a UIButton. The first is 300x360, the second is 210x70. The `imageview` contains a catalog image, the `button` says "open catalog".

I would like to position elements in the main view according to these requirements:

- the two elements should be centered horizontally, namely the center.x coordinates should be all equal (view, image and button);
- the two elements should be centered vertically in the following way: separator (flexible) - imageview - separator (fixed, let's say 30 pts) - button - separator (flexible). The topmost and bottommost separator should have the same size (this is the meaning of centered).

I cannot make this to work using NSLayoutConstraint.

So far, what I did, has been centering the X coordinate of the two elements using `NSLayoutAttributeCenterX` and `NSLayoutRelationEqual` to the same `view` attribute.

The last part, according to my idea, is to fix their vertical alignment.
I tried using `@"V:|-[imageview(360)]-[button(70)]-|"` but it won't work (`Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.`).

If I use `@"V:|-[imageview(360)]-[button]-|"` I get everything partially ok. Namely, the top part is perfect but the button is stretched so to fill the gap between the internal separator and the bottom of the view.

How can I make those elements to be fixed-sized and to let Auto-layout to just figure out how to place them in the view?

Comment: In iOS 9, look at UIStackView and UILayoutGuide for solving these sorts of problems.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to do it by doing something like this:

```
NSNumber *sepHeight = @60.0F;

// Center the two views horizontally
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                     multiplier:1
                                                       constant:0]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                     multiplier:1
                                                       constant:0]];

// Position the two views one below the other, using the separator height defined above
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[imageview]-sepHeight-[button]"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(sepHeight)
                                                                    views:views]];

// Force the button distance from the bottom to be the half of the size of the content
CGFloat constant = (imageview.frame.size.height + button.frame.size.height + [sepHeight floatValue]) / 2.0;
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                     multiplier:1
                                                       constant:constant]];
```

The tricky part is the constant value. That value is the half of the height of all the views, including their separators. This means that, if the imageview's height is 360, the button's height is 70 and the separator is 60, that constant will be (360 + 70 + 60)/2 = 245.

There should be a smarter way, indeed, but for now I think this is ok.

Comment: Clever! Good example of using the indirectness of Auto Layout thinking, and the coefficient and constant. So, one way to describe it is  Coefficient = 0.5 Constant = (imageHeightConstant + imageButtonVerticalSpaceConstant + buttonHeightConstant )  Or did I miss something...? The constants could be stored as CGFloat variables or properties and adjusted for appropriate sizings... :)

Comment: No, the multiplier is applied to the self.view.frame.origin.y value and the constant is added to such value. I will now rewrite it using variables.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to approach this.

1. As @uchuugaka suggests, place your imageview and button in a container view.  You don't have the same centering problem if the subviews are pinned to the edges of the container (which you would size accordingly - height would be 360 + 30 + 70 == 460.  Then you can center this container in your view with a simple align-center-Y constraint.
2. You can use spacer views.  By adding two hidden views you can specify constraints to position them above/below your imageview and button, with equal heights such they act as springs.  Here's code that does this, using your dimensions:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView* imageview = [UIView new];
    imageview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    imageview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    UIView* button = [UIView new];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;


    UIView* spacer1 = [UIView new];
    spacer1.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent: 0.5];
    spacer1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    spacer1.hidden = YES; // comment out to show spacer!

    UIView* spacer2 = [UIView new];
    spacer2.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent: 0.5];
    spacer2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    spacer2.hidden = YES; // comment out to show spacer!

    [self.view addSubview: imageview];
    [self.view addSubview: button];
    [self.view addSubview: spacer1];
    [self.view addSubview: spacer2];

    NSDictionary* views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings( imageview, button, spacer1, spacer2 );

    NSArray* constraints;
    constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"V:|[spacer1(==spacer2)][imageview(360)]-30-[button(70)][spacer2(==spacer1)]|"
                                                          options: 0
                                                          metrics: nil
                                                            views: views];
    [self.view addConstraints: constraints];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageview
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:nil
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                         multiplier:1
                                                           constant:300]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:nil
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                         multiplier:1
                                                           constant:210]];


    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageview
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                         multiplier:1
                                                           constant:0]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                         multiplier:1
                                                           constant:0]];
}
```

Comment: I like the spacer views idea. Except that it reminds me of 90's HTML spacer gifs ;)

Comment: Spacer views or an extra container view, unless you know the (fixed) height in advance. Oh, well. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your vertical spaces equal to or greater than on the top of the image view and bottom of the button. 
But, this also sounds like it would be easier to simply have on additional view that contains your image and button. Then center that view V and H in the super view.

Auto Layout still means container views sometimes.

Comment: That should be ok but the problem is that if you create a container, you have the same problem in the container :)

Comment: Not at all. The container can be constrained to top of one sub view and bottom of other one.

Comment: You are correct. If you make the container's height to be the sum of all the heights (and the separators), then you get a good solution out there. I don't like very much the idea of having a supplementary view out there but I think the solution is maybe easier to understand compared to mine.

Comment: I cannot say one is better. There are trade offs to each solution. Auto layout is still young.